# Extending a derivation from a subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

This question is *Problem 9* of *Section 2.3* in *Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups* by Onishchik and Vinberg.

Let $L$ be a field extension of $\mathbb{C}$ (hence also a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra) and $B \subset L$ a subalgebra which is finitely generated over another subalgebra $A \subset B$.
Let $\partial : A \to L$ be a derivation (i.e. a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map satisfying the Leibniz rule), then there exists a unique derivation $\tilde{\partial} : B \to L$ which extends $\partial$.

The main issue for me is uniqueness, as I believe the following example shows. Let $A = \mathbb{C}$ be the field of complex numbers, $B = \mathbb{C}[x]$ be the ring of polynomials, and $L = \mathbb{C}(x)$ the field of rational functions. On $A$ we define the trivial derivation $\partial(\lambda) = 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Then anything $\mathbb{C}(x)$-proportial to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is an extension of $\partial$ to $B$, hence the extension is not unique.

What is wrong with my example? Is my example correct and uniqueness must be dropped?

Comment: In your example, $\frac{d}{dx}$ is not an extension of $\partial$, since it acts incorrectly on $x^2$. (It gives $2x$ instead of $0$.)

Comment: $x^2$ is not in $A$, so it is not a problem how $\frac{d}{dx}$ acts on it.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I misread that. I did find a copy of the text and found a slightly different statement of the problem, though - my copy has the assumption $B$ is algebraic over $A$. Under this situation, there is a unique extension which you can find by playing around with the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed that **algebraic**.